# How Manage two opencart application

Tags: opencart-module

I have two open cart application. I want to do like , when i add product in first application ,that product also be added in to second application. How to do that  share some suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried anything, please share some code that you have tried and add some more details to narrow the question down. See this [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i did not use any code ..till now. i was thinking ..to connect both database, is it good or not.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart has multistore option by Default.
Why don't you use opencart multistore?
Link: http://docs.opencart.com/administration/multi-store/

Even if you have already running eshops, you can join them together. More effort there but still, you can do it this way.